# How to disable auto input volume adjustment in Sound Settings

Tags: gnome, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, audio-recording

How do you disable automatic input volume adjustment?

I'm trying to record audio, and I'm finding my input levels are constantly being thrown off because Gnome/PulseAudio/ALSA/something is automatically lowering my input volume when a peak is found.

If I open the standard Gnome Sound Settings, and set the Input volume to 100%, then make a loud sound, Gnome automatically lowers the volume. Then everything else it records after that is softer and lower than before, which ruins the recording. I'm find with whatever clipping it's trying to avoid. How do I disable this "smart" feature so my input volume stays where I set it?

[This](question is similar) but seems specific to Skype (which I don't have installed), and is not what I'm asking about.